# I am trying to calculate the product price before the discount

Tags: python, django

I am trying to calculate the product price before the discount through the product price and the discount percentage
The question is: how do I write this equation price / (1-discount%)  into the template in Django
Example:

```
<span class="old-price">{{......}} L.E</span>
```

```
class Product(models.Model):
    seasonChoices = (('summer','summer'),('winter','winter'),('both','both'))
    ageChoices = (('men','men'),('kids','kids'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, default='no description for this model', null=True, blank=True)
    season = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="both", choices=seasonChoices)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="men", choices=ageChoices)
    sale = models.IntegerField()
    img1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d')
    img2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    img3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    img4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.ManyToManyField(Size)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: You should *not* do this in the template, but in the model.

Comment: Please share the product model...

Comment: Where is the discount in the model?

Comment: sale field is discount

Answer (score 0):

````
I solved it finally
```
class Product(models.Model):
    seasonChoices = (('summer','summer'),('winter','winter'),('both','both'))
    ageChoices = (('men','men'),('kids','kids'))
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=0)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=200, default='no description for this model', null=True, blank=True)
    season = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="both", choices=seasonChoices)
    age = models.CharField(max_length=50, default="men", choices=ageChoices)
    sale = models.IntegerField()
    img1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d')
    img2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    img3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    img4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='products/%y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True)
    size = models.ManyToManyField(Size)
    availability = models.BooleanField(default=True)

@property
def get_old_price(self):
    return self.price / (1-(decimal.Decimal(self.sale)/100))
```
````